# Extract the main article text from a Wikipedia page using Python

Tags: python, parsing, extract, wikipedia

I've been searching for hours on how to extract the main text of a Wikipedia article, without all the links and references. I've tried wikitools, mwlib, BeautifulSoup and more. But I haven't really managed to.

Is there any easy and fast way for me to take the clear text (the actual article), and put it in a Python variable?

SOLUTION: Omid Raha solved it :)

Comment: Asking Google for "wikipedia python" I see third item being wikipedia python package. Searching "wikipedia" on http://pypi.python.org shows it as the first one. At it provides 5 minutes quick start explaining exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use this [package](https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia), that is a python wrapper for Wikipedia API,

[Here](https://wikipedia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#quickstart) is a quick start.

First install it:

```
pip install wikipedia
```

Example:

```
import wikipedia
p = wikipedia.page("Python programming language")
print(p.url)
print(p.title)
content = p.content # Content of page.
```

Output:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)
Python (programming language)
```

Comment: You can do it in 10 lines without having to PIP install anything because Beautiful Soup is built into Ubuntu Python automatically: https://dev.to/ankitdobhal/wow-scraping-wikipedia-content-with-10-line-of-code-327l